# IPhone 6s+ stuck in infinite loop screen

Tags: iphone

I was playing on the computer today when I went to the toilet. After I came back, I saw a loading circle on my screen. I thought its just a update but that wouldnt make sense because I didnt click anything. Then I thought I can just wait some minutes but now its already 4 hours. Ive been looking for solutions but **I got a specific problem!**

I cant press the Home and Power Button at the same time since my **Home Button is broken**. And I cant find any solution how I can restart my phone otherwise.

I tried everything but I just cant restart it.

Comment: Don‘t write solved into the question, accept the answer instead with the checkmark at the left.

Answer (score 2):

After 4 hours of waiting, the battery was finally empty.
Then I was able to normally start the phone! :)